# iOS Facebook integration with signin does not work when Setting is signed in

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Ok, this is probably something very common, but I cannot find the solution anywhere. When using the Facebook SDK to handle logging in as a SSO, it works great in the iOS simulator. However, on the actual device, it fails in one very specific instance: If the iPhone/iPad is signed into Facebook via the Settings in iOS, it comes back with "Session Closed: User cancelled login" (this message is generated when the error received is of the FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled type). I have tried every instance of this:

- Facebook iOS app installed and Signed In with Settings logged in **[FAIL]**
- Facebook iOS app installed and not signed In with Settings logged in **[FAIL]**
- Facebook iOS app not installed and Settings logged in **[FAIL]**
- Facebook OS app Installed and signed In with Settings not logged in **[SUCCESS]**
- Facebook iOS app Installed but not logged in and Settings not logged in **[SUCCESS]**
- Facebook iOS app not installed and Settings no logged in **[SUCCESS]**

This all has to do with the Settings being logged in to Facebook. Now I know others have their apps able to have Facebook integration with Settings being signed in, so what am I missing? Here is my sign in code:

```
- (IBAction)loginWithFacebook:(id)sender {
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    }
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info",@"public_profile",@"email"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler: ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
        // Retrieve the app delegate
        AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        // Call the app delegate's sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
        [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
    }];
}
```

Here is my code that handles all of this from the AppDelegate:

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error {
    // If the session was opened successfully
    if (!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen){
        NSLog(@"Session opened");
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler: 
            ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
              NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
              NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSString *firstName = user.first_name;
                NSString *lastName = user.last_name;
                NSString *facebookId = user.id;
                NSString *email = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
                [Data facebookLogin:facebookId email:email firstName:firstName lastName:lastName];
            }
        }];
    return;
    }
    if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed){
        // If the session is closed
        NSLog(@"Session closed");
    }
    // Handle errors
    if (error){
        NSLog(@"Error");
        NSString *alertText;
        NSString *alertTitle;
        // If the error requires people using an app to make an action outside of the app in order to recover
        if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error] == YES){
            alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
            alertText = [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error];
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Notice" message: alertText delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        } else {
            // If the user cancelled login, do nothing
            if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
                // This is the part that gets called, right here!
                NSLog(@"User cancelled login");
                // Handle session closures that happen outside of the app
            } else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession){
                alertTitle = @"Session Error";
                alertText = @"Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.";
                NSLog(@"%@",alertText);
                // Here we will handle all other errors with a generic error message.
                // We recommend you check our Handling Errors guide for more information
                // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
            } else {
                //Get more error information from the error
                NSDictionary *errorInformation = [[[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"] objectForKey:@"body"] objectForKey:@"error"];
                // Show the user an error message
                alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
                alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please retry. \n\n If the problem persists contact us and mention this error code: %@", [errorInformation objectForKey:@"message"]];
                NSLog(@"%@",alertText);
            }
        }
        // Clear this token
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        // Show the user the logged-out UI
    }
}
```

I understand this is a long post, but I figured it would be more beneficial to have all of the information available when talking about this.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. I think what is happening is that the native iOS login machinery chokes on the `@"public_profile"` permission (or more likely the server response to it that it is getting from Facebook). To verify, try to remove this permission from your permissions array.

This is an annoying problem, since the Facebook docs state that this permission is now obligatory.

Comment: Oddly, when I updated to the 3.14.0 API it started to work correctly.  I think there may be an issue with the 3.13.1 SDK.

Comment: @regeint: Good, but the problem went away for me anyway after I updated to the latest Facebook SDK.